# ¿Que programas y conocimientos son necesarios para crear una página web, que muestre un mensaje de un sensor en raspberry pi?

Tags: base-de-datos, webservice, servidor, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Buenas a todos, estoy viendo tutoriales por internet, lamentablemente no cuento con una raspberry... pero quiero seguir avanzando en esto.

He visto proyectos mas complejos en raspberry y esta vez quisiera que alguien me ayude con información, sobre qué necesito, para crear una página web o servidor web, donde pueda mostrar un mensaje cada vez que se detecte cambios en un sensor conectado a una raspberry pi...

Para ser directo, **¿cómo creo una página web y puedo llegar a hacer esa conexión?, ¿qué programas y conocimientos debo buscar para realizar esto?**,

Lamentablemente no podré realizar todo esto, pero si me ayudan en cuanto a como crear una página web, actualmente tengo MySQL, python en mi ordenador, vi muchos vídeos donde se usa Apache, aunque no se precisamente que es, también DreanWeaver, PhpAdmyn, LAMP... y demás.

Por favor, si alguien me podría decir que debo instalar para comenzar a aprender a crear páginas web, se los agradecería mucho, ya que hay ciertas cosas que no veré en la U hasta semestres avanzados y ya quiero ir viendo todo esto... aunque tal vez este pidiendo mucho, no se, pero no pierdo nada intentar preguntar

Comment: Hola Alvaro. Esta pregunta se basa en opiniones porque no hay una unica tecnologia para hacer esto y cada uno puede darte su recomendacion. Tambien es muy amplia. Mira [ask] para ver como hacer preguntas de calidad. Yo diria que la borrases y ya que tienes 20 de rep, entra en el [chat] a ver si alguien puede orientarte. Si investigas, lo intentas y tienes problemas concretos puedes pregutnar aqui si sigues la guia de Como preguntar que te pasé. un saludo

Comment: Instálate WAMP. Contiene Apache y MySQL y sólo con eso y un editor de texto puedes comenzar a realizar alguna web sencilla en local con HTML / PHP...

Comment: Hay muchas alternativas. Es muy común encontrar desarrollos en python que tienen sobre él un apache, un lighttpd o un nginx. Estos tres últimos son servidores web, sirven documentos HTML, imágenes, etc.. pero para servir código dinámico (PHP, python, etc) deben configurarse adecuadamente. ¿Qué lenguaje quieres usar? ¿Sabes algo de desarrollo de páginas dinámicas haciendo uso de javascript y/o lenguajes del lado del servidor? No cambia nada de un servidor linux normal a una raspberry. Danos algo más concreto.